# How to synthesize this derivative security using plain vanilla call options?

Tags: options, derivatives

A derivative security pays a cash amount *c* if the spot price of the underlying asset at maturity is between K1 and K2, where 0< K1 < K2 and expires worthless otherwise.

Q: how to construct this derivative security using plain vanilla call options?

Could anyone tell me how to construct this type of derivative security specifically and generally? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy a [K1, K1+w] call spread and sell a [K2, K2+w] call spread, where w is as small as possible.  The amount of notional of these you will need is c/w.   The limit of this as w goes to zero is the payoff you desire.  In practice you will be limited to whatever strikes are available to trade.